# transactional constraints check in mysql

Tags: mysql, constraints

I want to do something like that:

1) start transaction
2) run query1 ignoring constraints
3) run query2 ignoring constraints
4) check constraints:
4a) if they are all right - commit
4b) also rollback

example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `atable`;
CREATE TABLE `atable` (
  `id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `btable`;
CREATE TABLE `btable` (
  `id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_id`  int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `b_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `atable` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

first run of this script is pass....second is not because btable references to atable, so it fails on "drop table atable".

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you put the two `DROP TABLE` statements at the top of the script in the correct order?

Comment: because i don't want to do it with hand...this examples is simple, but when there is much more tables and dependencies... interesting if such functionality is exist in mysql